# Google Script MYSQL QUERY with Variables from google sheets

Tags: mysql, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Ok so I've been pretty much learning on my own and I ran into a problem that I cant seem to find a solution for.

The main goal is I have a google sheet with a start and end date that the user can change, the script pulls those dates and uses them in a MySQL query to pull the data between that date range.

Example: start date = 10/1/2021, end date = 10/22/21
Query: "select * from Table, where table.date >= start date AND table.dat <= end date"

See my code example below:

======================================================

```
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
 var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('DR_Campaign_Report');
 var getStartDate = sheet.getRange(1,2).getValue();
 var startDate = Utilities.formatDate(getStartDate,"GTM","MM/dd/yyyy");
 var getEndDate = sheet.getRange(1,5).getValue();
 var endDate = Utilities.formatDate(getEndDate,"GTM","MM/dd/yyyy");
 var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(url, username, password);
 var stmt = conn.createStatement();

 var results = stmt.executeQuery 
    ( 'SELECT m.Campaign as "Campaign",\n' +
      'count(m.Campaign) as "Leads",\n' +
      'count(m.Duplicate) as "Dups",\n' + 
      'count(m.Campaign) - count(m.Duplicate) as "Valid Leads",\n' +
      'count(m.AppSet) as "Appts",\n' + 
      'SUM(IF(m.ZepID != "",1,0)) as "Transferred Appts"\n' +
      'FROM intakeMani m\n' +
      'WHERE date(m.IncomingDate) >= date('startDate') and date(m.IncomingDate) <= date('endDate')\n' +  
      'OR date(m.AppSet) >= date('startDate') and date(m.AppSet) <= date('endDate')\n' +
      'GROUP BY m.Campaign with rollup'
    );


The Error is here in the WHERE clause when its attempting to pull the google script variables startDate and endDate.
'WHERE date(m.IncomingDate) >= date('startDate') and date(m.IncomingDate) <= date('endDate')\n' +  
      'OR date(m.AppSet) >= date('startDate') and date(m.AppSet) <= date('endDate')\n' +
```

I attempted the double "'startDate'" and is still errors. see attached pic.
[image]

Comment: dates need to be in double quotes so use `date("'startDate'")` and mysql will understand the query

Comment: I tried that, still errors, see the pic I added to the end of my post.

Comment: try `date("'+startDate+'") ` for all date varables

Comment: Well I can save it now, so it fixed that but its not pulling any data. I attempted to do the query with the dates in MySQL workbench and it works perfectly.

I have a separate script in google sheets that does the current days report that pulls from the same database, so I know its not a connection issue.

Comment: hm debugging is your part but what is in results?

Comment: Thats the thing, no results except the headers are pulled from the database. its something to do which how google scripts is handling the dates I think.

Comment: the dates have the wrong format for mysql see if you can make them #2021-01-31

Comment: I think i fixed it, date('+startDate+') is showing results. no "
TY for your input and help.

Comment: Its odd if I format the date like yyyy-MM-dd I get no results but if I format the date like MM/dd/yyyy, I get results but they are partial not showing all. Odd

Comment: are you sure you have a date column and not string? Because 2021-01-31 works all the time

Comment: According to my workbench, the date that is being filtered is a date, and the INT= datein

Comment: And the query works correctly in mysql workbench if I just manually inter the dates at date('2021-10-01')

So its the format in the google script that isnt working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Snippit of the code]

I fixed it, I had double " in the var getStartDate/GetEndDate fields and need to add " to the query "'+startdate+'"

Thank you for your help.